# Need help getting a value from database for use on a form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

The way I want to set it out as you can see, I want to connect to my database, get a value from a table and set a radio button on a form to be pre-selected when the page loads. This is for a quick maintenance mode project I am working on.

I want it to work like this if you don't quite understand still:

I set maintenance mode to "ON" and then submit the form. When the page reloads I want the On option to be checked on the form and vice versa when I turn it off.

At the moment, when I request the value from the database and echo it, I get the correct value. But on the form, it doesn't select any radio buttons. The closest I have gotten to it working is when the wrong button is selected.

This is the code I am using:

```
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Maintenance Mode Options</legend>
    <label>Set Maintenance Mode </label><br />
    <?php
    $conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die( mysql_error() );
    mysql_select_db($database) or die( mysql_error() );
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM maintain WHERE id='1'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql2) or die( mysql_error() );
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "Maintenance Mode is:".$res['value'];
    }
    ?>
    <label><input type='radio' name='selval' value='ON' <?php if ($res['value'] == "ON")     
    {           
    echo "checked='checked'";} ?>>ON</label><br />
    <label><input type='radio' name='selval' value='OFF' <?php if ($res['value'] ==     
    "OFF") {            
    echo "checked='checked'";} ?>>OFF</label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason why you're using two `>>` in the label? The second should be escaped.

Comment: A label should have a `for` attribute, that contains the id of the radiobutton it belongs to. Apart from making your HTML valid, that also improves usability, by allowing your users to click the label as well, and allowing screen readers to better understand the structure of your page.

Comment: The reason it has two greater than signs is because one is closing the php statement and the other closes the input attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ($res['value'] = "ON"
```

should be

```
<?php if ($res['value'] == "ON"
```

You are now assigning the value 'ON' to $res['value'] instead of checking if it already has that value.

Comment: Then there's probably another error. Are you sure the values are `ON` and `OFF`? If they are different, even if just the case is different, both comparisons fail and neither radiobutton will be checked. There could be other errors in your script as well, but 'it doesn't work' isn't very helpful.

Comment: The values of the buttons are ON or OFF. And when I select ON and submit the form, I can see that it changed on the database to ON. And when I echo the result of the query, it confirms that  it works. 'code' echo "Maintenance Mode is:".$res['value'];

Comment: So that part works. Which part doesn't? Or maybe you'd better start a new question for that, so some pairs of new eyes can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, "checked" will turn on the check, and absence of "checked" will turn it off.

Therefore:

"checked=yes"
"checked=nope"
"checked=whatever"

will all turn on the check.

I might be wrong, but that's my discovery in FF22.

Comment: That is true, but the entire `checked` attribute is only outputted if the condition is met. So that part should be working alright.

Comment: Not true - the code outputs "checked" regardless of the state.

Comment: Check again. There's an actual `if` statement there that checks the state. It outputs `checked='checked'` for one radiobutton or the other (but never both), depending on the state. Only problem is that neither will be checked if the state is neither `ON` nor `OFF`.

Comment: Yup, probably just above my skill level.